# Phalcon Relationship between yourself?

Tags: entity-relationship, phalcon

I wrote a `Foo` class with Phalcon. The `Foo` Model is initialized like this.

```
 $this->hasMany('id', 'Foo', 'parent_id', ['alias'=> 'children']);
```

Foo class has `parent_id` which is realted to `Foo id`.

```
class Foo extends Model {

   public $id;

   public $parnet_id;

   public $name;

}
```

Then want to get list with children

```
$foo = Foo:find();

$children = $foo->children;
```

Now it returns very big object. I want get children which have a parent_id same as fetched foo.

What is wrong? Is it has some logic?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing it right. Just when dumping Phalcon Model objects the whole DI gets printed, that's why you are confused. You can however iterate the children without any problems. Also try dumping like this:

```
print_r($foo->children->toArray());
```

This way you will see the children printed as array.

Comment: print_r($foo->toArray()); it returns only 3 fields - id, parent_id and name, and print_r($foo->children->toArray()); returns undefined children

Comment: Then check your $foo query. You are using $foo = Foo:find(); find() returns multiple results. Try using findFirst() to get only 1 record and then you can get its children.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to avoid toArray() function? Now I am trying to display children name

Comment: toArray() is just useful when debugging your results. You can iterate over $foo->children with normal foreach and print children's attributes.